# javascript closure show omit result

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new in javascript, and try some coding. Look at this code snippet, why i got the result 2 not 3?

```
var cbsample = function (cb) {

    var value = 1;
    console.log(value);
    return cb(value)(value);

};

var myvalue = cbsample(function (value) {

    value += 1;
    console.log(value);
    return function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        return value += 1;
    };

});

console.log(myvalue);
```

when i am calling the callback, then it changed the value to 2, but the closure doesn't take this new value(2), it takes the old value(1). Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the closure doesn't close over `value` actually :-) You have given the inner function a `value` parameter as well which will introduce a local variable, shadowing the outer one. So, no, it doesn't take the old (outer) value, it doesn't take the new (outer) `value`, but it takes a *different* `value` (which just happens to be `1` as well). 
Change it to

```
return function (v) {
    console.log("old value (from the closure):", value);
    console.log("new value (the arguments):", v);
    return value += v; // update closure variable and return 3
};
```

And you might change the `value` variable in your `cbsample` function as well to identify the differences :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably this line:

```
return cb(value)(value);
```

You are calling the outer function `cb` and the result of that function with the same argument `value`, which has at that time the value 1.

```
 var cbsample = function (cb) {

    var value = 1;
    console.log(value);        //1
    return cb(value)(value);   //return cb(1)(1);

};

var myvalue = cbsample(function (value) {

    value += 1;
    console.log(value);           //2
    return function (value) {     //this function will get called with 1 as argument
        console.log(value);
        return value += 1;        //return 2
    };

});

console.log(myvalue);             //2
```

To fix this you can just remove the argument of the inner, returned function in the function call as well as in the definition:

```
 return cb(value)();

 //....

 return function () {     
     console.log(value);
     return value += 1; 
 };
```